# jQuery script in head and dynamically added form

Tags: jquery

I have got a problem with executing a submission of dynamically added (by function) with two scripts in HEAD.

My HTML is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Web Page</title>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="js/forms.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I dynamically by function adding a form into  and trying to submit the data it doesn't work. All required code for execution the form is in **js/forms.js** I suppose it doesn't see the dynamic objects.

The form which is being added dynamically looks like (with jQuery code):

```
$('#container').append("<form class='input-form'><input type='text' id='login' /><input type='password' id='password' /><input type='submit' /></form>");
```

And the script is:

```
$('form.input-form').on('click', '#sendbutton', function () {
preventDefault();
var value_login = $("#login").val();
var value_password = $("#password").val();
alert(value_login + value_password);
});
```

Would anybody suggest how to make it working in **jsfiddle**? Or what I am doing wrong?

The real example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gu5qnfw1/2/

Comment: create a jsfiddle to replicate your problem.

Comment: Are you using $(document).ready(function(){}) ????

Comment: Yes Ideal Bakija the function which dynamically adds the form and content of the **forms.js** are inside of $(document).ready(function(){})

Comment: As a side note, IDs ***must*** be unique on document context, if that matters...

Comment: That jQuery code has a syntax error (you can't break lines in strings like that in JavaScript; you could if you put a backslash before the newline).

Comment: T.J. Crowder I just broke them for representing here. For better presentation...

Comment: @Think Different please find the jsfiddle here:  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gu5qnfw1/)

Comment: @qqruza use `$(document).on('submit','#sign-in-form',function (e) { ...` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Think Different